# HTML5 video not responsive

Tags: css, html, video

I can't get to display my video when my video in my page when my `<video>` is wrapped by a parent container. I'm actually trying to display a responsive video.

Here is a link to the codepen I made : 
http://codepen.io/ChucKN0risK/pen/YwQLZa

**HTML :**

```
<div class="media-wrapper video-wrapper">
  <video class="video-wrapper__video" src="http://www.louischenais.fr/src/video/Mobile_It_Changes_Everything.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.video-wrapper__video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nevertheless if I give a width to my video wrapper then my video is displayed. I've just updated my pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the video wrapper width.

```
.video-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you write wrong video tag. I write correct video tag and write the css for image and video.

Here is the [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QygZwN?editors=110)

```
 <div class="media-wrapper video-wrapper">
       <video class="video" controls>
        <source src="http://www.louischenais.fr/src/video/Mobile_It_Changes_Everything.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video> 
  </div>
```

CSS Code for image and video ..

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
.video {
  width:100%;
  max-width:800px;
  height:auto;
}
```